# Frame animation not working

Tags: android, animation, frame, android-drawable

I am attempting to have frame animation in the app I'm designing for class but the app keeps crashing despite the research I've done on exactly how to go about the frame animation. Is it more likely to be my android studio bugging out or the code is incorrect?

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/archerclip1" android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/archerclip2" android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/archerclip3" android:duration="100"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/archerclip4" android:duration="100"/>
```

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class FrameAnimation extends Activity {

AnimationDrawable archerAnimation;

@Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_frame_animation);

    Button btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

    Button btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

    ImageView imgFrameAnimation = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgFrameAnimation);

    imgFrameAnimation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animationone);

    archerAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)imgFrameAnimation.getBackground();

    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            archerAnimation.start();
        }
    });
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            archerAnimation.stop();
        }
    });

  }

}


   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 20232732 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 17MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflateChildElements(AnimationDrawable.java:324)
at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:294)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1215)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1124)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2630)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:17202)
at edu.wmich.lab5rfoste1057.FrameAnimation.onCreate(FrameAnimation.java:23)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please add crash logs .

Answer (score 0):

```
 ImageView imgFrameAnimation = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgFrameAnimation);
```

The images you're setting here are very large. Try resizing it to something smaller.